# Как получить знак «Провидец»?

Tags: поддержка, знаки, бета

В описании знака [Провидец](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/66/precognitive) говорится

> Поддержал предложение этого сообщества на сайте Зона 51 до того, как оно перешло на стадию открытой подписки.

Т. е. я предполагал, что получение этого знака уже давно невозможно.

Однако, если посмотреть на список участников, то видно, что он продолжает выдаваться - за 2018 год его получили уже 2 участника (последний из них - в августе), а за 2017 - целых 6:

> [image: скриншот]

Так что же надо сделать, чтобы его получить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вроде бы всё понятно. Участник не имел профиля на ruSO, но голосовал в своё время на Area51, потом, спустя несколько лет, зарегистрировался на ruSO и получил знак как и написано в требованиях к нему.

Обратите внимание, знак получен как раз в даты близкие к регистрации на ruSO:

> [image: профиль провидца]

Comment: но в описании знака ничего про требование зарегистрироваться не сказано

Comment: @mymedia так знак к сайту привязан, нет профиля на сайте — нет знака.

Comment: получается между голосованием и регистрацией прошли годы??

Comment: @mymedia типа того

Comment: @älёxölüt, я могу ошибаться, но вроде ruSO сразу стал открытой бетой, т. е. стадии закрытый беты вроде не было? Или была? И ещё, аза что собственно надо было голосовать, если сайт мигрировал с хэшкода, а не создавался новый?

Comment: @Qwertiy надо смотреть за что голосовали на зоне. Ромб позволяет? Наверное, нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy собственно, там даже не совсем голоса надо смотреть. Вот [участник](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/79159/hronom?tab=stats) вовсе без голосов, но получил знак [Pioneer](https://area51.stackexchange.com/badges/205/pioneer?userid=79159) за руСО как раз.

Comment: *точных дат регистрации в профиле не видно* — вроде есть же фраза типа "Участник в течение 2 месяцев" и можно навести курсор на "2 месяцев"

Comment: @АндрейNOP у меня нет курсора на сенсорном экране :) можете отредактировать вопрос, приложив соответствующую картинку, если хотите.

Comment: С ПК вы больше не работаете?

Comment: @АндрейNOP пока писал ответ — нет.