# Определиться с переводом для новых знаков и категорий

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

Обратил внимание, что у нас на сайте появилось пять новых [знаков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges):

> **Lifejacket**
>
> Answer score of 5 or more to a question score of -2 or less that goes on to receive a score of 2 or more
>
> **Lifeboat**
>
> Answer score of 20 or more to a question score of -3 or less that goes on to receive a score of 3 or more
>
> **Documentation Beta**
>
> Contributed 3+ substantive pieces of documentation during the private beta
>
> **Documentation Pioneer**
>
> Contributed 3+ substantive pieces of documentation in the first month of documentation
>
> **Documentation User**
>
> Получил как минимум один знак за вклад в Stack Overflow Documentation

Также была введена новая категория «Retired Badges»‎.

Всё это хозяйство надо творчески перевести в полном соответствии со стилистикой уже переведённых знаков.

Comment: Примечание: Lifejacket и Lifeboat введены вместо «реверса»‎, перемещённого в «Retired Badges».

Comment: Также заметил слетевший перевод описания у «аналитика». Отправил [на утверждение](https://ru.traducir.win/string/12407) старую версию, [вытащенную из Интернет-архива](http://web.archive.org/web/20161119221622/http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

Comment: а я только хотел вопрос задавать [«чё за грибы?»](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z57eL.png)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin отсыпьте )

Comment: Спасательные жилет и шлюпка

Comment: Подробнее о новых знаках: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/

Comment: @vp_arth или спасательный круг и спасательный катер (или даже МЧС)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"Retired Badges"** предлагаю перевести как **"Устаревшие знаки"**, о чём уже высказывались в [комментариях](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9289/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9#comment38407_9290). По моему мнению это лучше отражает тот факт, что ранее полученные знаки остаются, но вот новых уже выдавать не должны (хотя бывают и несколько не очевидные на первый взгляд [нюансы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8249/176217)).

По самим знакам предложения такие (довольно очевидны, как мне кажется):

> **Lifejacket**
>
> Answer score of 5 or more to a question score of -2 or less that goes on to receive a score of 2 or more

> **Спасательный круг**
>
> Получить рейтинг 5 или более баллов для ответа на вопрос с рейтингом -2 или менее баллов, что привело к получению вопросом рейтинга 2 или более баллов.

Почему круг, а не жилет? Как-то привычнее, и мне кажется, что утопающему всё же бросают круг (дают интересный ответ), а жилет должен быть надет несколько раньше (когда вопрос начал тонуть, но ответа ещё не опубликовано).

> **Lifeboat**
>
> Answer score of 20 or more to a question score of -3 or less that goes on to receive a score of 3 or more

> **Спасательный катер**

Описание аналогично предыдущему знаку с учётом иных цифр.

---

Знаки по Documentation у нас отсутствуют, поэтому переводить не вижу смысла.

Comment: Ещё не переведено "This badge is retired and is no longer awarded." на страницах устраревших меток. К примеру, [знак "Бродяга"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov готово.

Comment: как по мне надо не Катер, а шлюпка

Answer (score -2):

Предлагаю перевести "Retired Badges«‎ как «Аннулированные знаки».

Обоснование: [изначальное описание метки](http://web.archive.org/web/20161120053810/http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) — «Visited every section of the FAQ (retired)»; [в переводе](http://web.archive.org/web/20161119221622/http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) — «Ознакомился со всеми часто задаваемыми вопросами (аннулировано)». То есть примечание «retired», давшее название новой категории, было творчески переработано как «аннулировано»

Comment: Не знаю. Для меня "аннулировано" подразумевает полную анулированность, т.е, аннулируются даже ранее полученные. А это типо "знак на пенсии" :D

Comment: Исторические, устаревшие, недоступные для получения

Comment: @vp_arth антиквариат )

Comment: Ещё варианты: "скрыта", "не активна", "деактивирована".